# How to check the feature names for the one hot label using keras.utils.to_categorical?

Tags: python, keras

I would like to check the vocabulary after applying keras.util.to_categorical.

Eg.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
l = to_categorical(np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

when I print l[0]

My result:

```
array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
```

But I do not know whether what is this result represent? Whether is it 1 or 2 or 3 or???

What I wanted to know is which index represent which value from my numpy array

Please assist me on this and thank you.

Comment: `l[0]` represent `1`,`l[1]` represent `2` and so on.

Comment: So nothing change to the position? I see. Alright thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coding is fixed, positional one-hot encoding. `0` will always have a 1 in the first column, `1` will always have a 1 in the 2nd column and so on. Better understood using examples -

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.asarray([0,1,2])
arr2 = np.asarray([0,5,2])
arr3 = np.asarray([1,3,8])

print("arr1")
print(to_categorical(arr1))
print("arr2")
print(to_categorical(arr2))
print("arr3")
print(to_categorical(arr3))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
arr1
[[1. 0. 0.]
[0. 1. 0.]
[0. 0. 1.]]
arr2
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
arr3
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```